# Why aren't my Radio Buttons in my django template being able to be selected or displayed?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have been trying to get radio buttons to display on my Django website for a while now and keep running into issues.  I finally found out about manually rendered form fields and have been working with that.  When I get them to display, then I can't select them.  If I am able to select them, then I can't ever seem to push this information into the model.  I have tried a lot of different things, but keep coming up empty.  I read this article '[How to Render Django Forms Manually](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html)' hoping it would help, but I am not sure I understand where the difference between what he is doing and what I am doing.  If this is about not declaring a value, which is what I am understanding, then I don't know how to do it in a way to get the buttons to display.  Also, when I am able to select the radio buttons and POST, aside from it not posting to the model, I get this error `<ul class="errorlist"><li>month<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>` inside of the console.

Here is what I have right now.  I'll try to code comment what my attempts have been.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class CustomerData(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    npo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.npo

class Ebook(models.Model):
    ebook = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ebook
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import CustomerData, Ebook

MONTH_CHOICES = [
    ('January', 'January'),
    ('February', 'February'),
    ('March','March'),
    ('April', 'April'),
    ('May', 'May'),
    ('June','June'),
    ('July', 'July'),
    ('August', 'August'),
    ('September','September'),
    ('October','October'),
    ('November','November'),
    ('December','December')
]


class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    firstname = forms.CharField(label='First Name:', error_messages={'required': '*'}, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "Richard"}))
    lastname = forms.CharField(label='Last Name:', error_messages={'required': '*'}, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "Eby"}))
    npo = forms.CharField(label='Organization:', error_messages={'required': '*'}, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "The Coding Recruiter"}))
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email:', error_messages={'required': '*'}, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "email@example.com"}))
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Phone:', required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "XXX-XXX-XXXX"}))
    month = forms.ChoiceField(label='Month of Renewal/Expiration:', choices=MONTH_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerData
        fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'npo', 'email', 'phone', 'month']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        firstname = cleaned_data.get('firstname')
        lastname = cleaned_data.get('lastname')
        phone = cleaned_data.get('phone')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        month = cleaned_data.get('month')
        if not firstname and not lastname and not phone and not email and not month:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')



EBOOK_CHOICES = [
    ('Grant Writing', 'Grant Writing'),
    ('Volunteer Management', 'Volunteer Management')
]

class EbookForm(ModelForm):
    ebook = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=EBOOK_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), error_messages={'required': 'Ebook Choice Required'})
    class Meta:
        model = Ebook
        fields = ['ebook']

class RawContactForm(forms.Form):
    firstname = forms.CharField(label='First Name:', error_messages={'required': '*'}, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "Richard"}))
    lastname = forms.CharField(label='Last Name:', error_messages={'required': '*'}, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "Eby"}))
    npo = forms.CharField(label='Organization:', error_messages={'required': '*'}, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "The Coding Recruiter"}))
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email:', error_messages={'required': '*'}, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "email@example.com"}))
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Phone:', required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder" : "XXX-XXX-XXXX"}))
    month = forms.ChoiceField(label='Month of Renewal/Expiration:', choices=MONTH_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), required=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)  
    form2 = EbookForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form2' : form2,
            'form' : form
        }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        context = {
            'form2' : form2,
            'form' : form
        }
    if form.is_valid() & form2.is_valid():
        subject = 'FaithGuard Confirmation Email'
        # Also tried request.POST.get() and a few other things here
        fname = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
        lname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        ebook = form2.cleaned_data['ebook']

        ebook = form2.save()
        newcustomer = form.save()
    else:
         print('Not Valid')

    return render(request, 'landingpage/index.html', context)


# This is an alternative approach that I took to try and bypass the is_valid function since it seemed to be causing the issue, or so I think/thought
    def index2(request):
    form = RawContactForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RawContactForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            CustomerData.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    context = {
        'form' : form
     }

    return render(request, 'landingpage/bootstrap.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<form method='POST' action='' class="col s6" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- 4 different basic 4 approaches here -->

    <!-- {{form}} /// Radio buttons don't display and can't tell which is selected -->

    <!-- {{form.as_p}} /// Radio buttons don't display and can't tell which is selected -->

    <!-- {{form.as_table}} /// Radio buttons don't display and can't tell which is selected -->


    <!-- {{form.as_ul}} /// Radio buttons don't display and can't tell which is selected -->




  <!-- Slightly altered version I found on the Django Documentation -->
<!-- ////This is selectable, but doesn't push to the model -->
    <div class="fieldWrapper">  
            {{ form.month.errors }}
    <label>Month:</label>
    <br>
        {% for month, monthb in form.fields.month.choices %}
            <label>
             <input name="group1" type="radio" />
             <span> {{month}} </span>
            </label>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>




    <!-- /// Alternate approach to one above. Can't select the radio buttons, but each displays on screen as a radio button -->
    <div>  
        {% for a, b in form.fields.month.choices %}
        <input type="radio" name="phone" id="id_month">
        <span>{{a}}</span>
        {% endfor %} 


        <!-- /// I noticed that when I do it this way, if the label starts and ends next to itself, then it won't dispaly all 12 months as a radio button. -->
<div class="fieldWrapper">  
    {{ form.month.errors.as_text }}   
    <!-- ///// Also did this not using the as_text, but that had not change in affect -->
    {% for month, monthb in form.fields.month.choices %}
   <label>
  <input value='month' type="radio" />
     <span> {{month}} </span>
    </label>
    {% endfor %}
</div>




<div class="div right-align">
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" value='Save'>Submit</button>
</div>

</div>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I was using MaterializeCSS.  Once I removed that, it started working.  Noted for future projects, don't use Materialize